What is special about the εκκλεσια that Jesus says is 'my εκκλεσια'?

And I say also unto thee, That thou art Peter, and upon this rock I will build my church; and the gates of hell shall not prevail against it. [Matthew 16:18 KJV]

Jesus speaks these words to the apostle Peter and calls something 'my ekklesia'.
The question of 'the rock' and Peter is another question.
What interests me is the nature of the ekklesia that Jesus calls 'my ekklesia'.
Another question has asked if ekklesia could mean a gathering of unbelievers and, of course, it could do. But what of 'my ekklesia' ?
What is peculiar to 'my ekklesia' that causes it to stand out from all other ekklesias ?

Also, I notice that the original is :

οικοδομησω μου την εκκλησιαν [TR - Stephanus, Beza, Elzevir and Scrivener all identical]


I will build of me the ekklesia [my own literal]

Does this necessarily translate to 'my ekklesia' ?
Or is Jesus emphasising that this ekklesia is built of him, specifically, and is not just a general group of people gathering themselves together ?

It is special because it is an entirely new thing that starts to form when the Father in heaven reveals to the Apostle Peter the significance of just who Jesus is. As Jesus exclaims in delight to Peter that flesh and blood had not revealed this to him, he goes straight on to declare that he will build his ecclesia.
Due to the internal, spiritual revelation to Peter, an unseen, spiritual formation begins, and all those who are added to this ecclesia of Christ's must have the same revelation from God so that they both understand the significance of Jesus being the Son of God, the Christ, and they confess it. Context shows that individuals like Simon Peter who make that particular confession of faith as to who Jesus is, form that ecclesia. Indeed, only individuals who make that same confession will be built up by Jesus into his ecclesia. And that confession is only enabled by the Father in heaven revealing it to individuals.
The first task is to grasp the meaning of that Greek word, ecclesia, for many people quite misunderstand it, due to the Greek word having been translated “church”.
The English word 'church' is neither a translation nor a transliteration. It falls well short of what the Greek word conveys, which is a word rooted in the verb kaleo, 'to call'. The preposition ek, 'out of', is joined to it, to create a compound which literally means, 'That which is called out'. Kaleo is used 147 times in the New Testament and means 'to call'. This extends to the words kletos (called - 11 times), and klesis (calling - 11 times).
How could anybody get from - that which is called out - to buildings where people go to? Could the English idea of a building that is called "a church" be an attempt to have people think that if they go to services of worship held in such buildings, or who get their names listed on a roll of members who say they belong to that particular church (as opposed to being supportive members of the church building further down the street, or all other church buildings in the city and in the country) that this proves they are Christians?
The first task has been achieved: the word ecclesia means those who are called out. The words 'assembly' or 'congregation' give the sense, but never the word 'church'! The second task is to understand what this calling is, in order to answer whether this "is not just a general group of people gathering themselves together?"
Christians are people who have been called out of this world to form a new gathering - those who belong to Jesus Christ by faith. Can every person attending a service of worship in buildings called 'churches' identify with having been called out of this world to follow Christ? Absolutely not! Some can, but others cannot. That is because the call is distinct, and comes from God, to individuals. He calls them as an act of grace on his part. 'Calling' is not man's calling upon God, but God's calling to men. He chooses who he will call. Consider how clear the New Testament is about this critically important fact. Here is a running list of texts.
"That the purpose of God according to election might stand, not of works, but of him that calleth" (Rom. 9:11). "It pleased God, who separated me from my mother's womb, and called me by his grace, to reveal his Son in me, that I might preach him among the heathen." (Gal. 1:15-16) "And know that all things work together for good to them that love God, to them who are the called according to his purpose." Rom. 8:28
Perhaps the clearest statement proving those two points in this answer is:

"Unto the church of God which is at Corinth, to them that are sanctified in Christ Jesus, called to be saints, with all that in every place call upon the name of Jesus Christ, our Lord... But we preach Christ crucified, unto the Jews a stumbling block, and unto the Greeks foolishness; But unto them which are called, both Jews and Greeks, Christ the power of God, and the wisdom of God... For ye see your calling, brethren, how that not many wise men after the flesh, not many mighty, not many noble, are called: But God hath chosen the foolish things of the world to confound the wise; and God hath chosen the weak things of the world to confound the things that are mighty; and base things of the world, and things which are despised, hath God chosen."  1 Corinthians 1:2 & 23-24 & 26-28 K.J.

There are very many more texts that could be cited to continue this massive theme running through the New Testament: God chooses those whom he will call out of the world and into fellowship with Christ Jesus, and fellowship with fellow believers in Christ. Those individuals - collectively - constitute the ecclesia of Christ.
Not a single unbeliever can be reckoned in their number, for it is God who does the calling and Christ does the symbolic building. Those so called then go on to call upon the name of God and Christ, but they would never have chosen to join with such a mixed company as Christ builds up, together, in fellowship. People who gather themselves together do so for reasons such as, mutual standing in society; exclusive elevation of a peer group; getting a specific common goal achieved, from finding a partner to making a powerful team.  But the group of believers gathered by Christ worship together in such a way that unbelievers coming into their midst are convicted, and declare that God is truly among them. See 1 Corinthians 14:24-25. They see the difference between those called out of the world, and those who are part of the world (themselves). Those called out of the world by God have made the same declaration of faith Peter made about just who Jesus is, and those ones throughout the centuries constitute the ecclesia, the spiritual 'body' of Christ. They are special because unless God had revealed to them how special his Son is, causing them to declare that in faith, they would never have congregated together in fellowship.

+1 Excellent answer. Years ago someone ask Billy Graham what's the first thing your going to ask God when your in heaven? He said, "Why me."

Up-voted +1. Yes, indeed. Excellent. Very much appreciated, Substantial work.

As the OP would be aware, the word, ἐκκλησία (ekklesia) means "those called out", or, "called out ones".  The word was usually used in a political sense of people called out of a crowd by a politician or zealot (of any kind) to hear a political discourse/debate.
Now, it immediately follows that those who are called out, must be called out by someone.  In the NT, the word is used of the following groups:

Christians who are called out by Jesus to be His followers, eg, Matt 16:18, 18:17, Acts 5:11, 8:1, 3, 9:31, etc
Ancient Israel who were called out of all nations to be God's special people, eg, Acts 7:38.  Compare Deut 4:20, 7:6, 27:18, 28:9, Jer 13:11, etc, where God calls Israel His "special people".
A political rally - people called out of the general populace to rally support for some cause; such were called out by the rally organizer, eg, Acts 19:32, 39, 41.

The point becomes obvious - the one doing the calling out can say that those called out are his/her "ekklesia".
This is reinforced (for Jesus' ekklesia) by several statements in the NT such as:

Matt 16:18 - And I tell you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build My church, and the gates of Hades will not prevail against it.
Heb 12:23 - and to the assembly, to the church of the firstborn having been enrolled in the heavens ...
Eph 5:23 - for the husband is head of the wife as also Christ is the head of the church, He Himself Savior of the body.
Col 1:18 - And He [Jesus] is the head of the body, the church, who is the beginning, firstborn out from the dead, so that He might be holding preeminence in all things
1 Peter 2:9 - But you are a chosen people, a royal priesthood, a holy nation, a people for God’s own possession, to proclaim the virtues of Him who called you out of darkness into His marvelous light.
Titus 2:14 - He gave Himself for us to redeem us from all lawlessness and to purify for Himself a people for His own possession, zealous for good deeds.
Col 3:12 - Therefore, as the chosen of God, holy and beloved, clothe yourselves with hearts of compassion, kindness, humility, gentleness, and patience.

Thus, Christ's church, the ones He calls out from the world, belong to Christ for the following reasons:

Jesus calls out the members of the church
Jesus paid the eternal ransom for sin for all the members of the church
Jesus is the head and governing authority of this church/ekklesia.
Jesus' ekklesia consist of "special people" whose task is to proclaim goodness and grace of Jesus.


It can indeed be translated that way. If we look at the English Greek Bible we see:
Greek:

κἀγὼ δέ σοι λέγω ὅτι σὺ εἶ Πέτρος καὶ ἐπὶ ταύτῃ τῇ πέτρᾳ οἰκοδομήσω μου τὴν ἐκκλησίαν πύλαι ᾅδου οὐ κατισχύσουσιν αὐτῆς

Literal English

I also now to You I say - yourself are Peter And at this the rock I will build of Me the church [the] gates Hades not will prevail against
her


The HELPS Word-studies says:

1577 ekklēsía(from 1537 /ek, "out from and to" and 2564 /kaléō, "to
call") – properly, people called out from the world and to God, the outcome being the Church (the mystical body of Christ) – i.e. the universal (total) body of believers whom God calls out from the world and into His eternal kingdom.

We are a people called out from the world and to God. This is beyond just any assembly or gathering; it is a congregation that is set apart for a divine purpose.
What makes “my εκκλησία” special?:

Divine origin: “My εκκλησία” was initiated by Jesus, giving it a
divine calling and foundation.
Spiritual fellowship: It is a community of believers who
share a common faith and commitment to follow Jesus.
Spiritual mission and purpose: This εκκλησία is tasked with carrying out
the will of God on earth and declaring His salvation.
Eternal destiny: Unlike secular assemblies, “my εκκλησία” is part of
the eternal kingdom of God, with a promise of everlasting life.


The rock on which God will establish His church is in the confession
Peter has just made: that Jesus is "the Christ, the Son of the living
God" (Matthew 16:16). (bibleref)


The phrase could be understood in two interconnected ways:

Possessive sense: “My εκκλησία” indicating ownership. It is the
assembly that Jesus claims as His own, distinct from any other
gathering. (Matthew 16:18, John 10:14-15, Ephesians 5:25)


And I also say to you that you are Peter, and on this rock I will build My church, and the gates of Hades shall not [a]prevail against
it. (Matthew 16:18)


I am the good shepherd; and I know My sheep, and am known by My own.
15 As the Father knows Me, even so I know the Father; and I lay down
My life for the sheep. (John 10:14-15)


Constitutive sense: The translation rendering “of me”
shows that the εκκλησία is built from Jesus and by Jesus (which we have scriptural support for). It is not
just a group of people who decide to gather. Jesus' εκκλησία is a
community formed by the call and will of Jesus, founded upon His
teachings, His life, His death, and His resurrection. (1 Corinthians 3:11,
Ephesians 2:19-22, Colossians 1:18)


For no other foundation can anyone lay than that which is laid, which
is Jesus Christ. (1 Corinthians 3:11)


Now, therefore, you are no longer strangers and foreigners, but fellow
citizens with the saints and members of the household of God,
having been built on the foundation of the apostles and prophets, Jesus Christ Himself being the chief cornerstone, in whom the whole
building, being fitted together, grows into a holy temple in the Lord,
in whom you also are being built together for a dwelling place of
God in the Spirit. (Ephesians 2:19-22)


And He is the head of the body, the church, who is the beginning, the
firstborn from the dead, that in all things He may have the
preeminence. (Colossians 1:18)

